# How to get max_length of CharField in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to set maxlength html attribute in django template but when I try to get the value I specified in my model by using {{field.max_length}} nothing is displayed. I can get any other field value just fine.

Relevant Snippet:

```
{% for field in form %}
            {% if "_color" in field.name %}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-init="{{field.name}}='{{field.value}}'" ng-model="{{field.name}}" ng-change="{{field.name}}_picker={{field.name}}" placeholder="{{field.label}}" maxlength="{{field.max_length}}">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The field you get by iterating trough your form is actually a [`forms.BoundField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f630373b929bc62bf4d66d60c532f7832e5fbe67/django/forms/forms.py#L488), and does not have all the attributes of your `Field`. You can access the `Field` instance through the `field` attribute of your `BoundField`. So, `{{ field.field.max_length }}` should work.